# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and not sure why

Tags: java, arrays, object, indexoutofboundsexception

I am learning about object oriented concepts right now. I wrote a simple class to accept user input scores but I am getting an out of bounds exception and I'm not sure why! I don't see why this would be accessing indexes over than 4? Here is the code:

The HighScores class which I am instantiating 5 objects into an array:

```
public class HighScores
{
    String name;
    int score;

    public HighScores()
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.score = 0;
    }
    public HighScores(String name, int score)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    void setScore(int score)
    {
        this.score = score;
    }

    int getScore()
    {
        return this.score;
    }
}
```

The program manipulating HighScore objects:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighScoresProgram
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HighScores[] highScoreObjArr = new HighScores[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < highScoreObjArr.length; i++)
        {
            highScoreObjArr[i] = new HighScores();
        }
        initialize(highScoreObjArr);
        sort(highScoreObjArr);
        display(highScoreObjArr);
    }

    public static void initialize(HighScores[] scores)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the name for for score #" + (i+1) + ": ");
            String temp = keyboard.next();
            scores[i].setName(temp);
            System.out.println("Enter the the score for score #" + (i+1) + ": ");
            scores[i].setScore(keyboard.nextInt());
        }

    }

    public static void sort(HighScores[] scores)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
        {
            int smallest = i;

            for (int j = i; i < scores.length; i++)
            {
                if (scores[j].getScore() < scores[smallest].getScore())
                    smallest = j;
            }

            HighScores temp = scores[i];
            HighScores swap = scores[smallest]; //This is where I'm getting the out of bounds exception.
            scores[i] = swap;
            scores[smallest] = temp;

        }
    }

    public static void display(HighScores[] scores)
    {
        System.out.println("Top Scorers: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(scores[i].getName() + ": " + scores[i].getScore());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot! I've been banging my head trying to figure it out. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get your problem resolved. In the future, if you're getting an exception, post the whole message to make it easier to debug, and ideally note which line the exception is getting thrown from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i guess below line is issue

```
for (int j = i; i < scores.length; i++)
```

try updating sort function as below

```
 public static void sort(HighScores[] scores)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
        {
            int smallest = i;

            for (int j = i; j < scores.length; j++)
            {
                if (scores[j].getScore() < scores[smallest].getScore())
                    smallest = j;
            }

            HighScores temp = scores[i];
            HighScores swap = scores[smallest]; //This is where I'm getting the out of bounds exception.
            scores[i] = swap;
            scores[smallest] = temp;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is when the loop ends it means that `i` is no longer smaller then `scores.length`. which means that you are basically checking the of bound when you exit the loop below the line:

```
for (int j = i; i < scores.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 for (int j = i; i < scores.length; i++)
```

You're incrementing i instead of j here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are incrementing same vairable `i` in outer and inner loop. Your outer loop runs 4 times but inner loop increments the value if `i` further. Use a different variable in inner for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = i; j < scores.length; j++)
```